# windows 8.1 wifi hotspot connected but android page is not opening

Tags: windows-8.1

I have to connect my laptop internet into my android phone. i am using 3g USB dongle. I have tried virtual wifi router but for sharing its not showing my 3g dongle connection. 
however i did netch hosted network in CMD and it showing connected in my android and i share my connection to hosted network coonection but its get showing connected in my android but page is not opening in my android.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that you have shared the internet from USB dongele adaptor to the hotspot adaptor..

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: goto network connections, then change adapter settoings, from there select the dongle network adapter, right click and goto sharing tab , from there select sharing and choose the hotsport network in it (some wireless conection with a * sometimes)

Comment: Update your answer.